# Java trying to get all cached

Tags: java, caching

I'm caching some certain players on my little game and now in my run method I want to check everyone who is cached and give them their reward, insted of getAllplayersOnline and check if they are in that certain map, I just cached the ones enter that map.

```
public static HashMap<Integer,MapleCharacter> fishlist = 
               new HashMap<Integer,MapleCharacter>();
```

Then I put

```
fishlist.put(chr.getId(), chr);
```

now in my run method i tried

```
                 if(UseChairHandler.fishlist.containsKey(chr.getId())) {
//do stuff
```

but it didn't work...any ideas?

Comment: "it didn't work" -- care to elaborate?

Comment: Even if im cached, it doesnt give me any items and i checked, its this part tht is wrong.

Comment: Have you verified that the `fishlist.put` line is being executed?

Comment: No concurrent map ? Your app is singlethreaded ?

Answer (score 0):

the entryset allows you to loop over the entire map

```
for(Map.Entry<Integer,MapleCharacter> entry:fishlist.entrySet() ){
    //entry.value() is a MapleCharacter in the map
}
```

Comment: Entire map? and what does this mean //entry.value() is a MapleCharacter in the map

Comment: before you do that, find out why the map doesn't cache the content you believe it should. Is chr.getId(); always returning the right result?

Answer (score 0):

Add more debug output. A `System.err.println(fishlist)` can do wonders.
Is chr.getId() always returning the correct ID?
Also, if your game is multi-threaded, you will run into problems if you don't properly synchronize access to the map.

Comment: If you could make me a synchronized method that checks for anyone thats cached, i'll love you and try to learn off it!

Comment: use a ConcurrentHashMap for starters